# jQuery autocomplete with IDs

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I'm trying to use [`jQuery autocomplete.result()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete) to get the ID associated with the name value the user selects.  Here's the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#DonorName").autocomplete($('#ajaxListMatchingDonorNamesUrl').val())
        .result(function (evt, data, formatted) {
            $("#SelectedDonorId").val(data[1]);
        });
</script>
```

And here's the HTML I'm trying to use it from:

```
Html.TextBox("DonorName", "")

<input
    id="ajaxListMatchingDonorNamesUrl" 
    type="hidden" 
    value="path" />
<input type="hidden"
    name="SelectedDonorId" />
```

Firebug shows the correct values in data[] (e.g., [0]=Name and [1](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete)=ID).  However, when the form POSTs, the `SelectedDonorId` value is empty.

I tried removing the  from the html, but that simply removes the key from the param collection after the POST.

What am I missing?  Thx.

Comment: One more try to show the html...

TextBox("DonorName", "")
input id="ajaxListMatchingDonorNamesUrl" 
                   type="hidden" 
                   value="Path"
input type="hidden" name="SelectedDonorId"

Comment: After your autocomplete script runs, do you see a value for SelectedDonorId in Firebug?

Comment: Html.TextBox("DonorName", ""), are you using C#?

Comment: Jay--Yes, C# (inside MVC 1.0)
Mopoke--I'm still trying to find the fb hierarchy tree that would have the document elements (e.g. SelectedDonorId).  New to fb :-(

Comment: Suggest you add tags for C# and/or MVC. Also, you can hover your mouse to the target element, then press Ctrl+Shift+C to trigger firebug, it will show you where this element is inside the resultant html.

Comment: After I read your question carefully, I don't think I fully understand your logic flow here. So do you have the autocomplete js code embedded in the same page as where you fire the html.textBox() and other html (two inputs)? Also, since SelectedDonorId is input:hidden, why do you want to overwrite it? Are you trying to hide the input type first then make it visible with the returned html?

Answer (score 0):

What is the type of your data?

I believe autocomplete is expecting a list of items not a string.
when I added split(" "), your code worked for me (for a space separated list of strings).

`$("#DonorName").autocomplete($('#ajaxListMatchingDonorNamesUrl').val().split(' '))`

I also changed data[1] to data.

`$("#SelectedDonorId").val(data);`

in other words...data is not an array when I get it back.

EDIT: Adding from comments...add the 'id' attribute to the hidden input box instead of the 'name' attribute.

Comment: Thanks, santosc, but in my case I'm passing in a list in the form "Name|GUID\n".  This means that data[0]=selectedName and data[1]=GUID.  FF does indeed show the array contains the proper values.  But I'm not getting the GUID value assigned to the hidden input attribute so I'm getting nothing back in my controller.

Comment: you're going to hate this...

but your input type is name='SelectedOwnerId'.
If you want $('#SelectedOwnerId') to work, you're going to have to change it to id='SelectedOwnerId'.  (read: change name=  to id= in your hidden input attributes)

Answer (score 0):

Change this

`$("#SelectedDonorId").val(data[1]);`

to

```
$("input[name=SelectedDonorId]").val(data[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone.  Simply adding id='SelectedDonorId' got everything working, just as Santosc thought it would.

Note:  Data[] is indeed correct because I'm passing back a list in the form

name|id"\n"

where name = what autocomplete will work on and show,

id is the reference I want to use in the POST method,

"\n" is what is usually is (newline).

autocomplete has some cool magic in that .result does the 'split', and puts the name in Data[0] and the id in Data[1].  So just referencing it is all that's needed.